# python/tkinter add the individual letters of a word to a label on button press

Tags: python, button, tkinter, label

```
from tkinter import *

# Create a window
spell_window = Tk()

# Give the window a title
spell_window.title('Spell Table')


table_Var = StringVar()

## table = ['T', 'a', 'b', 'l', 'e'] ## I think it needs to move through a list???

def spell_table():
    s_table = monty_Var.get()
    s_table += 'T' #Currently adds a 'T' each time the button is pressed
    monty_Var.set(s_table)



the_label = Label(spell_window, width = 10, textvariable = table_Var,
                  font = ('Arial', 30), bg = 'red')

the_button = Button(spell_window, text = 'Next letter', command = spell_table)

the_label.pack(padx = 0, pady = 0)

the_button.pack(padx = 40, pady = 0)
```

So basically i have created the label and button and need to spell out the word Table by pressing the Next letter button. Just not sure how to make it move through the table list and add them to label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fixed code:

```
from tkinter import *

spell_window = Tk()

spell_window.title('Spell Table')

table = ['T', 'a', 'b', 'l', 'e']
count = 1

def spell_table():
   global count, table
   the_label.config(text=table[:count])

   if count < len(table):
      count += 1



the_label = Label(spell_window, width = 10, text = "", font = ('Arial', 30), bg = 'red')

the_button = Button(spell_window, text = 'Next letter', command = spell_table)

the_label.pack(padx = 0, pady = 0)

the_button.pack(padx = 40, pady = 0)

spell_window.mainloop()
```

I deleted useless variables and added a 'count' variable that increases with each click. And yes, you did need a list for that, a tuple would do too. I changed "the_label"'s text from

```
'textvariable = ' to 'text = ""'.
```

I also sliced the list according to the 'count'. [:count] = anything before count's index value. also the if statement is there just to be efficient, because we don't need to allocate more space to the variable after it exceeded the index value of the 'table' list. You were also missing a

```
spell_window.mainloop()
```

at the end. Hope this helps!